# Detect backspace on dynamically created span within editable div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have editable div wherein there's a span that is dynamically created. I want to delete the whole span element once backspace is triggered on it. So far what I have done is on below jsfiddle link, the backspace detection is not working.

https://jsfiddle.net/mt15199/Lp4s6c4c/3/

HTML

```
<div id="input" contenteditable><span id="var" style="border: 1px solid gray; background-color: yellow;">var:purchase_price</span> I look like an input span</div>
```

JQUERY CODE

```
alert("ready!");

$('#input').on('keydown', '#var', function() {
    var key = event.keyCode || event.charCode;

    if( key == 8 || key == 46 ) {
        return false;
        alert("backspace detected!");

       }
  });
```

Comment: You select `span#span` but you have no `span#span` in your HTML...

Comment: I just corrected that, still the same

Comment: Maybe the answer helps you @MarlZ15199

Comment: Similar code found. May help you http://jsfiddle.net/IrvinDominin/U8wnK/

Comment: Thank you Rohit but my knowledge with native javascript is just basic

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your can use `window.getSelection().anchorNode.parentNode.tagName` to get the tag name that has been changed and if it is a `span` element remove that.

```js
alert("ready!");

$(document).on('keydown', '#input', function(e) {
  var key = event.keyCode || event.charCode;

  if( key == 8 || key == 46 ) {
    if(window.getSelection().anchorNode.parentNode.tagName ==='SPAN'){
      window.getSelection().anchorNode.parentNode.remove();
    }
    alert("backspace detected!");
    return false;
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="input" contenteditable><span id="var" style="border: 1px solid gray; background-color: yellow;" contenteditable>var:purchase_price</span> I look like an input span</div>
```

Comment: Hi Angkit, thank you for your answer that works. But I want to happen is detect the keydown on span element with id #var only not on other element or text within the div.

Comment: That span is not editable so how can you detect `keydown`. `keydown` works for elements that are editable.

Comment: I see, will it work if I add the same attribute to span - <span 
 contenteditable>

Comment: But in that case your `span` will look like a input box and user can change the content of that `span`. If that is acceptable by you then you can surely change your `span` but I do not think that will be a good idea. @MarlZ15199

Comment: Actually, the span is editable even I do not add contenteditable attribute.  Regardless I even add it the keydown is not working on it.

Comment: Send me the JSfiddle for that @MarlZ15199

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/171377/discussion-between-ankit-agarwal-and-marlz15199).

Comment: @MarlZ15199 please check now

Comment: Thank you so much Sir Ankit :) accepted the answer.